# How to enable remote debugging for windows azure java project using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, azure, azure-compute-emulator

I am working with Windows Azure using java as programming language. I am trying to debug my application using eclipse. I have configured remote debugging settings for my worker role at endpoint 8090. Every time i try to debug my application (running on local emulator) eclipse throws and error message saying "unable to connect to remote VM, connection reset". Please help.

P.S.: I am a newbie in JAVA(also with eclipse).

Comment: Can you telnet to port 8090 at all?

Answer (score 0):

Under Eclipse got to 
run->debug configuration.
Click on "Remote Java Application" in left

And enter the required attributes like below and try.

Under connection Properties enter [Host and Port], make HOST default if configure in local

Mark the breakpoint and run the application it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ashu, I have tried it several time and eclipse is keep saying "unable to connect to remote VM, connection reset".